# Slight confusion about the definition of a Vector Space

Tags: vector-spaces

The way a vector space is introduced is by saying that **vector space is a set V on which two operations + and · are defined, called vector addition and scalar multiplication** . This works well when we are shown that in a sense polynomial functions are vector spaces, however I'm left with a slight confusion. In the above example, the notion of adding and multiplying 2 polynomials was already laid down. What I don't understand is, whether what "addition" and "scalar multiplication" means in the context of a "new" vector space is arbitrary. Let me demonstrate  what I mean with an example:

Suppose $A$ is the set of all sheep with a certain color and size. If I say that we can "add" 2 sheep together, and the resulting sheep is the one that their offspring would grow up to be, color and size vise, and we can "multiply" a sheep by a real number, which would result in said sheep growing to $ x $ times it's size. Assuming all the axioms are satisfied (not sure what the identity-sheep is ), is it fair to say that $A $ is a real vector space?

Comment: $A$ is not a real vector space since the offspring of two sheep is never one of the parents, so there is no "additive identity sheep". However, the multiplicative identity is 1. Unless you define the "zero sheep" as no sheep, then define the "offspring"(since there can't be any) to be the "parent" that is not the zero sheep. Still, negative sheep needs to be defined, e.g. as anti-matter sheep that annihilates a normal sheep, etc...

Comment: But since we are talking about abstract sheep, the offspring doesn't have to **be** the parent, it's enough if it has the same color and size. Sure the set has to be infinite, include "zero sheep", "antimatter sheep" etc... Point is, is the definition of the 2 operations arbitrary?

Comment: It is certainly possible to have exotic sets with exotic multiplication and exotic addition be considered a vectorspace, yes, even one involving sheep.  You specifically used the phrase "**real** vector space" which implies that the scalar field is the real numbers.  Your example happened to not work mostly because the very concepts of "adding" sheep and "multiplying" a sheep by a real number don't seem to match with our intuition about such things... but in general there is nothing innately wrong about sheep as an example collection of elements for your vector space...

Comment: So long as you are able to adequately define the elements in your space, adequately define addition of elements in your space, adequately define the scalar field, adequately define scalar multiplication of an element of your field with an element of your space, *and show that all of the necessary properties hold* for your space, field, and interactions between these... then it doesn't matter what flavor they happened to have.

Comment: Your statement "Suppose $A$ is the set of all sheep with a certain color and size" is not a mathematical one since "sheep" and "color", etc. are not mathematically defined. Therefore, you have not really defined the set $A$ and any discussion of it as a vector space is moot.